# AWS: ALB responding either immediately or after 130 seconds

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-elb

I am using an ALB and trying to exploit the concept of host-based routing to place several hosts (with 1-1 mapping with target groups) behind it.

So I have 5 urls each one of them being forwarded to a different TG (and therefore instance in my case), in the likes of

```
https://path1.mydomain.com
https://path2.mydomain.com
```

(...and so on)...

What I noticed is that I get a binary behavior, i.e. the ALB will respond either almost immediately (i.e. < 1.sec) or in about 130 seconds.

```
$ for X in `seq 60`; do curl -Ik -w "HTTPCode=%{http_code} TotalTime=%{time_total}\n" https://path1.mydomain.com -so /dev/null; done
HTTPCode=200 TotalTime=130.157
HTTPCode=200 TotalTime=131.053
HTTPCode=200 TotalTime=131.050
HTTPCode=200 TotalTime=0.485
HTTPCode=200 TotalTime=130.533
HTTPCode=200 TotalTime=0.467
HTTPCode=200 TotalTime=130.586
HTTPCode=200 TotalTime=0.477
HTTPCode=200 TotalTime=130.567
```

This goes for all the paths.

Any idea where this behavior might be coming from?

Here are the response headers (I **always** get `200`, no matter the delay)

```
$ curl -kI  https://path1.mydomain.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 05 Dec 2018 17:03:14 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 1617
Connection: keep-alive
Server: nginx
Last-Modified: Thu, 19 Jul 2018 09:52:09 GMT
ETag: "5b505f49-651"
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

**edit_1**: although I am registering 2 subnets/AZs for the ALB, all of my instances are in the same AZ/subnet, for what that matters;

**edit_2**: when hitting one of the public instances' IPs directly:

```
$ for X in `seq 60`; do curl -Ik -w "HTTPCode=%{http_code} TotalTime=%{time_total}\n" http://18.9.48.141 -so /dev/null; done
HTTPCode=200 TotalTime=0.005
HTTPCode=200 TotalTime=0.007
HTTPCode=200 TotalTime=0.005
HTTPCode=200 TotalTime=0.007
HTTPCode=200 TotalTime=0.007
HTTPCode=200 TotalTime=0.005
HTTPCode=200 TotalTime=0.005
HTTPCode=200 TotalTime=0.005
HTTPCode=200 TotalTime=0.010
HTTPCode=200 TotalTime=0.005
HTTPCode=200 TotalTime=0.005
HTTPCode=200 TotalTime=0.008
```

**edit_3**: it is also **not** a dns resolution issue since a 100 iteration of the `dig` command returns immediately with no error.

**edit_4**: This is where `strace` of the `curl` command hangs:

```
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(443), sin_addr=inet_addr("51.53.132.130")}, 16) = -1 EINPROGRESS (Operation now in progress)
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLOUT|POLLWRNORM}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 199)  = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLOUT|POLLWRNORM}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 0)    = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLOUT|POLLWRNORM}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 1000) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLOUT|POLLWRNORM}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 1000) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLOUT|POLLWRNORM}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 1000) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLOUT|POLLWRNORM}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 1000) = 0 (Timeout)
```

**edit_5**: Some `tcptraceroute` iterations to the public IP where the `curl` command hangs

```
$ for i in `seq 10`; do sudo tcptraceroute 51.53.132.130; done
traceroute to 51.53.132.130 (51.53.132.130), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  51.53.132.130 (51.53.132.130) <syn,ack>  2.109 ms  2.097 ms  2.230 ms
traceroute to 51.53.132.130 (51.53.132.130), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  51.53.132.130 (51.53.132.130) <syn,ack>  1.964 ms  1.954 ms  1.942 ms
traceroute to 51.53.132.130 (51.53.132.130), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  51.53.132.130 (51.53.132.130) <syn,ack>  2.148 ms  2.220 ms  2.208 ms
traceroute to 51.53.132.130 (51.53.132.130), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  51.53.132.130 (51.53.132.130) <syn,ack>  2.227 ms  2.214 ms  2.200 ms
traceroute to 51.53.132.130 (51.53.132.130), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  51.53.132.130 (51.53.132.130) <syn,ack>  2.181 ms  2.170 ms  2.159 ms
traceroute to 51.53.132.130 (51.53.132.130), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  51.53.132.130 (51.53.132.130) <syn,ack>  2.157 ms  2.221 ms  2.207 ms
traceroute to 51.53.132.130 (51.53.132.130), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  51.53.132.130 (51.53.132.130) <syn,ack>  2.228 ms  2.216 ms  2.203 ms
traceroute to 51.53.132.130 (51.53.132.130), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  51.53.132.130 (51.53.132.130) <syn,ack>  1.810 ms  1.962 ms  1.961 ms
traceroute to 51.53.132.130 (51.53.132.130), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  51.53.132.130 (51.53.132.130) <syn,ack>  1.695 ms  1.757 ms  1.852 ms
traceroute to 51.53.132.130 (51.53.132.130), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  51.53.132.130 (51.53.132.130) <syn,ack>  2.202 ms  2.187 ms  2.173 ms
```

It is evident that the huge lag is introduced by the Application Load Balancer.

Comment: I would remove all of the instances besides 1 and go from there. See which ones are the actually causing the delay. It seems that because of the pattern that some of the instances are truly healthy (instant response) and some are being weird.

Comment: I hesitate to to agree that your strace of curl shows a huge delay at the ALB.  Try a repeated tcptraceroute to the ALB address, ``tcptraceroute 51.55.192.130 443`` . Hopefully you will see the problem occuring and if it is happening at network hops before the ALB.   Do the ALB health checks use the same URL as the data requests?  There is a default 10 second timeout on them, that's why I ask.  Have you looked at instrumentation on the backend servers?

Comment: @Vorsprung updated my question with some `tcptraceroute` iterations

Comment: All health checks are on `/` and the traffic port;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the following:

I had assigned 2 AZs to my ALB and the subnet corresponding to one of these had no `0.0.0.0/0 --> IG` route.

Comment: Sir you are a gentleman for documenting this so well, I had exactly this